# Sql query guide me

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM   JLOAN_HI_CSVDATA
    WHERE jloan_hi_csvdata.INSERTEDDATE  >= TO_DATE('15-02-15', 'DD/MM/YY')
      AND  jloan_hi_csvdata.INSERTEDDATE  <= TO_DATE('19-02-15', 'DD/MM/YY')
      and STATUS = 'Success'
    ) AS Success,
    (
    SELECT  COUNT(*)
    FROM    JLOAN_HI_CSVDATA
    jloan_hi_csvdata.INSERTEDDATE  >= TO_DATE('15-02-15', 'DD/MM/YY')
    AND  jloan_hi_csvdata.INSERTEDDATE  <= TO_DATE('19-02-15', 'DD/MM/YY')
    and STATUS != 'Success'
    ) AS Failure,
    (
    SELECT  COUNT(*)
    FROM    JLOAN_HI_CSVDATA
    WHERE jloan_hi_csvdata.INSERTEDDATE  >= TO_DATE('15-02-15', 'DD/MM/YY')
      AND  jloan_hi_csvdata.INSERTEDDATE  <= TO_DATE('19-02-15', 'DD/MM/YY')
    ) AS Total ;
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Guide you where? You've posted bunch of code without any declaration what are you trying to achieve and what problem are you facing. So how can anyone guide you anywhere except http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask?

Comment: Several syntax errors. E.g no WHERE in second sub-select.

Comment: Look up the 'group by' clause in your sql reference.

Answer (score 2):

Do one `SELECT`, use `CASE` for conditional counting:

```
SELECT COUNT(case when STATUS = 'Success' then 1 end) as Success,
       COUNT(case when STATUS <> 'Success' then 1 end) as Failure,
       COUNT(*) as Total
FROM   JLOAN_HI_CSVDATA
WHERE jloan_hi_csvdata.INSERTEDDATE  >= TO_DATE('15-02-15', 'DD/MM/YY')
 AND  jloan_hi_csvdata.INSERTEDDATE  <= TO_DATE('19-02-15', 'DD/MM/YY')
```

Comment: thanks for this i want two more column from this table column name (csvdesc,data) how can i get all in one query.

Comment: Copy and paste rows from my query. Replace the column names and adjust the values.

Comment: SELECT COUNT(case when STATUS = 'Success' then 1 end) as Success,
       COUNT(case when STATUS <> 'Success' then 1 end) as Failure,
       COUNT(*) as Total
FROM   JLOAN_HI_CSVDATA
WHERE jloan_hi_csvdata.INSERTEDDATE  >= TO_DATE('15-02-15', 'DD/MM/YY')
 AND  jloan_hi_csvdata.INSERTEDDATE  <= TO_DATE('19-02-15', 'DD/MM/YY')
 union
 select csvdata,description from jloan_hi_csvdata                                           i want something like this i will be very thankful...

Comment: The UNION's different SELECT's must return the same number of columns, with matching data types. Start another question, where you specify sample data, and expected result!

Comment: i cant ask another question my repo is over i want to merge both query              select csvdata,description from jloan_hi_csvdata  and
 SELECT COUNT(case when STATUS = 'Success' then 1 end) as Success,
       COUNT(case when STATUS <> 'Success' then 1 end) as Failure,
       COUNT(*) as Total
FROM   JLOAN_HI_CSVDATA
WHERE jloan_hi_csvdata.INSERTEDDATE  >= TO_DATE('15-02-15', 'DD/MM/YY')
 AND  jloan_hi_csvdata.INSERTEDDATE  <= TO_DATE('19-02-15', 'DD/MM/YY')